# Converting raw frames into webm live stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, video-streaming, html5-video, webm

I have an ASP.NET application with the following set up:

1. A camera that captures raw RGB frames at a resolution 656x492
2. These frames are processed in my C# code (with some simple image
   processing)
3. The raw image is stored in a byte array (as well as wrapped in a Bitmap  container)
4. ***MISSING MAGIC: Convert raw image buffer to WebM stream***
5. On the other end I have a function `HttpResponseMessage` function that hooks up a WebM stream with a `PushStreamContent` function (inspired by this [blog post](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/)). This function pushes chunks of a video file to the website.
6. A Website that plays back the video.

I am struggling to figure out how to implement **point 4**. Right now I can only stream video files. But I would like to encode my raw buffer into a WebM container and stream that to my website. The central piece of code of **point5** looks as follows:

```
while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
{
    bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    length -= bytesRead;
}
```

Basically I would like to replace the `video.Read` function by somehow encoding my raw frames into a WebM format on the fly and storing them in `buffer`, so they can be pushed to the website as a live stream. Is there a straight forward way to do this? It's fine if some frames get dropped.

If there is an entirely different approach that is better then I am of course also open for suggestions.

Comment: Do you need to stream live or record and then stream the file?

Comment: @aergistal: I have to stream live. I am already able to record and then stream the file.

Comment: For live make sure you're encoding using a single continuous process if you use the pipe solution. Otherwise you will cause discontinuities in the output stream because the timestamps reset (to values near zero) with each new spawned process.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you can do on the server (outside of deploying a web app), you might consider writing your buffer into a pipe, then use `ffmpeg` running in the background to create your stream from it with something like `-f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24 -video_size 656x492` as input parameters.

Comment: I have complete control over the server! But is it possible to encode only chunks of the video?

Comment: We use this all the time (allthough on Linux, the concepts are the same), just start/stop the ffmpeg process as needed. FFmpeg can also (via the -t parameter) be told to only encode upt to so and so mayn seconds.

Comment: This sounds like a good plan and it almost works. I am able to pipe to ffmpeg, but I am unable to pipe the ffmpeg-output back to my application.

Comment: I opened a new question about my ffmpeg problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32157774/74660

Answer (score 1):

The [WebM Project](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/) offers DirectShow filters for playing and encoding WebM

> We provide DirectShow filters for playing and working with WebM on Windows. Once the filters are installed on your system, applications that use the DirectShow framework (such as Windows Media Player, and others) will be able to play and **encode WebM media**

There is also a [FFmpegInterop Microsoft](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/) initiative which uses the [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) multimedia framework.