# ffmpeg output pipeing to named windows pipe

Tags: c#, windows, ffmpeg, pipe, named-pipes

*This question is related to my previous question: [Converting raw frames into webm live stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32140086/74660)*

I want to pipe a video to ffmpeg and read it back through another pipe, but I cannot pipe the output of `ffmpeg.exe` to a named pipe on windows.

My definition of the pipes in C#:

```
NamedPipeServerStream p_to_ffmpeg;
NamedPipeServerStream p_from_ffmpeg;
p_to_ffmpeg = new NamedPipeServerStream("to_ffmpeg", PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
p_from_ffmpeg = new NamedPipeServerStream("from_ffmpeg", PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
```

And then I start `ffmpeg.exe` in a separate process with the following options: `-f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -video_size 656x492 -r 10 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i \\.\pipe\to_ffmpeg  -c:v libvpx  -pass 1 -f webm \\.\pipe\from_ffmpeg`

ffmpeg.exe refuses to write to the pipe with the following error : `File '\\.\pipe\from_ffmpeg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]`

When I replace the "output pipe" with a file name, it works like charm: `-f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -video_size 656x492 -r 10 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i \\.\pipe\to_ffmpeg  -c:v libvpx  -pass 1 -f webm output.webm`

**How do I get ffmpeg to write to a named pipe in windows?**

Edit: When I force to write to the pipe with ffmpeg's `-y` option, I get the following error: `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Error number -32 occurred`

Comment: Drop the `-pass 1` parameter because you're not doing two-pass encoding and post full console output please.

Comment: @aergistal: Thanks for your comment. It seems like I fixed the issue. I had to specify the buffer size of the pipe. Why should I drop `-pass 1`? I thought this option would specifically ensure that libvpx only does one pass. I now run into the problem that ffmpeg stops processing. But I cannot rule out that this isn't a problem with the receiving pipe, because the pipe blocks on the read function.

Comment: @aergistal: console output: `Input #0, rawvideo, from '\\.\pipe\to_ffmpeg':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 77460 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 656x492, 77460 k
b/s, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
[libvpx @ 03a9ff80] v1.4.0
Output #0, webm, to '\\.\pipe\from_ffmpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 656x492, q=-1--1, pass 1, 200 kb/
s, 10 fps, 1k tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.58.100 libvpx
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))`

Comment: It's 1-pass by default. If you specify the `-pass 1` it creates a log file to keep the video statistics for the second pass (`-pass 2`) which never happens. In 2-pass encoding the first run analyses the video (and you can discard its output) and the second one does the actual encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like the problem can be solved by adding the `-y` (override) option to the ffmpeg command and specifying a buffer size for the pipe.

My ffmpeg command (see aergistal's comment why I also removed the `-pass 1` flag):
`-y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -video_size 656x492 -r 10 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i \\.\pipe\to_ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -f webm \\.\pipe\from_ffmpeg`

And defining the named pipe as follows:

```
p_from_ffmpeg = new NamedPipeServerStream('from_ffmpeg', 
    PipeDirection.In, 
    1, 
    PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, 
    System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 
    10000, 10000);
```