# Is it possible to grab a frame from a video stream and save it as png in another stream with ffmpeg?

Tags: c#, .net, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFMpeg with System.IO.Process to convert a seek-able in-memory video stream into a thumbnail. Piping the thumbnail out through stdout isn't a problem, but piping in the video is tricky.

My current code copies the entire video stream into stdin, which is very slow and unnecessary, because ffmpeg obviously doesn't need the entire file to get the first frame. Writing the stream to the file system and specifying its path as an input argument is also very slow, because the source video can be several gigabytes.

I have tried accomplishing this using existing libraries, such as AForge, FFMpegCore, Xabe.FFMpeg, xFFMpeg.NET and Accord.FFMPEG.Video, but unfortunately they can only work with actual files, not streams, and my input video is not available as a file.

The stream object that supplies the video fully implements seeking and random access reading functionalities, just like a file stream, so there is literally no valid reason for this to not be possible, besides the limitations of the APIs (or my knowledge).

As a last resort, I could use the Dokan.NET filesystem driver to expose the video stream as a virtual file so ffmpeg can read it, but that would be an extreme overkill and I'm looking for a better solution.

Below is my current code. For the sake of simplicity, I am emulating the input video stream with a FileStream.

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i - -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 -q:v 2 -c:v png -f image2pipe -";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();

var stream = File.OpenRead("test.mp4");
stream.CopyTo(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Flush();
process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Close();

var stream2 = File.Create("test.png");
var buffer = new byte[4096];
int read;
while((read = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    stream2.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

EDIT: 
It might be useful to clarify what kind of data does the input stream contain. It is basically a video file that can be in any commonly used format (avi, mp4, mov, ts, mkv, wmv,...). The extension of the video (as if it was a file) is also known.

Comment: Hey try named pipes. I've successfuly streamed live video to ffmpeg frame by frame through a named pipe in Windows. Some resources:
https://mathewsachin.github.io/blog/2017/07/28/ffmpeg-pipe-csharp.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157774/ffmpeg-output-pipeing-to-named-windows-pipe

Comment: Also you may want to specify some additional options for ffmpeg like more info about your video codec, framerate etc. because ffmpeg cannot seek named pipe afaik. Some options you may want to take a look at: `nostdin; thread_queue_size; analyzeduration; fflags nobuffer; probesize; guess_layout_max; s; video_size; c:v; framerate; r;`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have modified the code, but my original problem still persists. I only need a single frame from the first couple seconds of the video, and I don't know how many bytes do I need to pump into the named pipe. With a test video file, I have tried sending the first 5MB of the video, and it successfully extracted the frame. But i think there are other video formats where the decoder (ffmpeg in this case) must read some data from the end of the file for validation or something like that. This method wouldn't work with those files.

Comment: Yes that is sometimes the case. My guess is it's a problem with seeking - ffmpeg cannot seek named pipe, so you have to specify more information about your video - video size, codec, framerate etc. check my second comment.

Comment: FFMpegCore now supports streams, both for input and output