# Get rtsp ffmpeg(H264) stream from webcam and serve through asp.net core rest api

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming, rtsp, webapi

I have several webcams that offer rtsp ffmpeg(H264) streams, and i want to serve them through web api to web clients, so they don't have to know about their credentials.

The part of serving the stream to the client i have achieved it with a file from the filesystem, but i can't figure out how to deal with the rtsp stream.

Comment: See following code project : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Comment: I've got the frames using an existing dll i can store the frames in the disk and play de mp4 fine, but when the frames are consumed by an html5 client don't work. I've seen something about fragmented mp4, but i'm stuck.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What html5 tool are you using?  Does it work with a different html5 tool?

Comment: Thank you jdweng, it seems i have to convert the frames into webm stream, currently i'm working on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157774/ffmpeg-output-pipeing-to-named-windows-pipe